# Ajax Request is fine but does not redirect to PayPal

Tags: paypal, laravel-7

I am trying to integrate and my Ajax request to the PayPal is fine but it does not redirect a user to a PayPal login page.

Here is my Ajax Request:

```
 $.ajax('/createpayment',
                {
                    method: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json', // type of response data
                    success: function () {   // success callback function
                        console.log('success');
                        var elem = document.getElementById('error');
                        elem.style.display = 'none';
                    },
                    error: function () { // error callback 
                       console.log('errors');
                    }
                });
    }
```

and here my controller method:

```
public function payWithPaypal(Request $request) {

        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
        
        $products_ids = [];
        $quantities = [];
        
        $data = session()->get('data');
        
        
        for($i=0; $i<count($data);$i++){
            for($j=0; $j<1;$j++){
                $products_ids[$i] = $data[$i]['product_id'];
                $quantities[$i] = $data[$i]['quantity'];
            }
        }
        
        $products = Product::whereIn('id', $products_ids)->get();
        
    
        $items = [];
        
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $item = new Item();
            $item->setName($product->name)->setCurrency('USD')->setQuantity(Product::getProductQuantity($product->id))->setPrice($product->price);
            
            $items[] = $item; 
        
        }

        $item_list = new ItemList();
        $item_list->setItems($items);
        
        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('USD')
                ->setTotal(Product::getTotalPrice($products));
        
        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount)
                ->setItemList($item_list)
                ->setDescription('Your transaction description');        
        
        $redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirect_urls->setReturnUrl(route('status')) /** Specify return URL * */
                ->setCancelUrl(route('cancel-payment'));
        
        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('sale')
                ->setPayer($payer)
                ->setRedirectUrls($redirect_urls)
                ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
       
        /** dd($payment->create($this->_api_context));exit; * */
        
        
        
        try {
            $payment->create($this->_api_context);
            
            $response = array(
             
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg'    => 'Payment created successfully',
        );

            return json_encode($response);
            
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
                echo $ex;
        }
}
```

It gives the correct response. Response is given below

```
status: "success", msg: "Payment created successfully"}
msg: "Payment created successfully"
status: "success"
```

I am unable to find the problem because there are no errors, and no redirect occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate implementation recommendation:

Use this front-end code (no redirects, opens a modern in-context experience): https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Implement two routes on your server for that UI to call, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction': https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

Use this current v2 Checkout-PHP-SDK with Composer, as the previous v1 PayPal-PHP-SDK is deprecated:  https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK

Comment: But I must use redirect because my website flow is like that @Preston PHX

Comment: Time is short so alternate implementation is not possible...and which command is used to install current v2 Checkout-PHP-SDK through composer??
@Preston